# How to get servicenow survey responses using api

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

How can we get the servicenow survey questions and responses using API?

I need to get all the responses for a survey I created including the question, answer and the ticket number.

I tried to get the responses from asmt_metric_result table, got the string value only. How can I get the question and ticket number as well?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to fetch the same details and finally understood how they are linked. It goes like:

1. The `asmt_metric_result` table API response contains the user reponse (answer) for the given instance in `string_value`. It also has another key called `instance_question` which links to the question table.

   Ex:

```
"instance_question": {
"link": "https://servicenow.instance/api/now/table/asmt_assessment_instance_question/abcd",
"value": "abcd"
            }
```

Here the value refers to the `sys_id`

2. Now, when you query the `asmt_assessment_instance_question` table, it will give you other links. Ex:
   `https://servicenow.instance/api/now/table/asmt_assessment_instance_question?sys_id=abc`

   This will return a response with a list of other keys.

   Here you have to refer the `metric` key which will link to another table called `asmt_metric`.

   Ex:

```
"metric": {
                "link": "https://servicenow.instance/api/now/table/asmt_metric/def",
"value": "def"
            }
```

3. Now, you have to refer the `asmt_metric` table and it will return a response which has a key called `question` which will have the actual question. Ex:

```
"depends_on": "",
        "question": "I have reviewed the user list for terminated users.",
        "max": "1",
```

And, to get your Assessment instance number you can either refer the `instance` key returned in `asmt_metric_result` or `asmt_assessment_instance_question` responses.

You can also refer the `source_id` key in `asmt_assessment_instance_question` response as well.